# Comparison test of series with ln function

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to test convergence of series with comparison test in the next examples:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n} \right) 
$$

<strike>I know that:</strike>  (incorrect)

$$
\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right) < 1 + \frac{1}{2^n}
$$

Correct:

$$
\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right) \leq \frac{1}{2^n}
$$

<strike>Therefore</strike> (incorrect) $$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1+\frac{1}{2^n}\
$$

Therefore:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}\
$$

<strike>Is divergent, but that doesn't tell me anything because it is larger than the starting series. So how to solve this using comparison test?</strike>

Is convergent which implies that starting series is convergent as of rule:

Suppose that
$$
0 \leq  a_n \leq b_n
$$
for sufficiently large n, then:

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ diverges, then  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ diverges.

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges.

Comment: Nooo, $\log(1+x)\leq x$ for any $x\geq 0$, hence the given series is convergent by comparison with a geometric series.

Comment: your sum converges by the ration test

Answer (score 0):

$lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{{ln(1+x)}\over x}$ is the derivative of $ln(1+x)$ at $0$ and is $1$ this implies that $lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}{{ln(1+1/2^n)}\over {1/2^n}}=1$ so the serie converges since the serie $1/2^n$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** Take $\displaystyle v_n=\frac{1}{2^n}$ , and use limit comparison test by taking $\displaystyle u_n=\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$